# configuring server and client ports in Ember-Cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am making an Ember app using Ember-Cli which talks to a server side application. Because Ember-Cli projects run with their own server (on port 4200 by default), I have to run my server in development on a different port (`localhost:8080`) than the Ember app. In production, however, the two will be running on the same port.

Question: How can I configure Ember (in config/environment.js I presume) so that Ember-Data and all ajax requests will be made to localhost:8080 in development (in spite of the fact that the Ember app is running on 4200) and, in production, that Ember-Data and ajax requests will query whatever port the server side app is running on (which will be hosting the client side app).

[Ember-Cli docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments) mention that some configuration can be done (for example that you can change the port that Ember-Cli runs on), however, it doesn't say how to accomplish the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want ember to use a different port for your API depending on the environment? It sounds like you need have your application adapter grab a value from your environment file

```
//environment.js
var ENV = {
  ...
  apiHost: 'https://path-to-production-api.com',
  ...
}

if (environment === 'development') {
   ENV.apiHost: 'http://localhost:8080'
}
ENV.contentSecurityPolicy['connect-src'] += ' ' + ENV.apiHost;

//adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from 'portal/config/environment';
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   host: ENV.apiHost
});
```

Comment: so when you refer to my "API", you mean the database where I am storing and retrieving information (using Ember Data) and not some third party api service (for example, Twitter's api for collecting tweets).

Comment: Yup, whatever you have hosted on 8080 that you say provides the data. Honestly you can name the variables whatever you want in the config file just as long as you set the host key on the application adapter